# How do I change the default sort order on Windows Explorer and the File Dialogs

Tags: windows-explorer, sorting

My file dialog shows files sorted by date and I want it to sort alphabetically by filename.

Answer (score 15):

I was still getting inconsistent results with the various solutions.  This seemed to work best for me:

1. Open My Documents folder, Select **View - Details**
2. Either (A) move Date column to the far left or (B) right click on date column, select "More" and move Date to the very top (**Move Up** button)
3. Click on **Date** to sort by most recent
4. Select **View - Options**
5. Select **View** tab, **Apply to all folders**

This will always sort folders for that document type **by date** since it is the first column and saved as default view.

Comment: Only solution here that works for me (Windows 7)

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 7):

1. Open Windows Explorer (<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)
2. Click on the column you want to sort on (Name)
3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-click on the 'X' close button at the top

Edit: This appears to be a folder by folder setting.

Comment: This might have to be renewed from time to time, because Windows has a short memory.

Comment: @djhowell: because we're too slow?

Comment: I know he's technically right, but it's just a little abnormal to ask a (to my opinion very very simple) question and answer it within 2 minutes.

Comment: @Ivo: Happens all the time when you're "stuck" and then figure something out, in my experience.

Comment: @djhowell: It's OK to answer your own question: http://superuser.com/faq (last sentence in the first section)

Comment: Well for the record, I have tried this and I have not seen it work at all.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.

Comment: @AlanSE What OS? Did you go back to the same folder?

Comment: @KevinDriedger This is Windows XP.  Actually, I just tried changing the preferences to *remember* the view settings of each folder in the folder options menu.  This method works with that alteration, although I would prefer for the solution to do this for all folders at once, it does work with that setting so I find that it answers the question, although you might want to specify that option need to be set.

Answer (score 4):

As seen at [xpheads.com](http://www.xpheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windowsxp-general/3756-complete-loss-sort-order-open-dialog-box.html):

> To resolve this behavior, reset the default sort order:
>
> 1. Right-click Start > Explorer > `C:` partition
> 2. View menu > Details
> 3. Click the Name column to sort items by name > Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
> 4. Quit Explorer via the X in the upper-right corner > Release <kbd>CTRL</kbd> > Reboot
>
> NOTE: You must perform these steps exactly as they are listed; for example, do not quit Explorer by clicking Exit in the File Menu.

Comment: I don't understand the first step in this answer. Could you help? What is that path about? SOrry confused.

Comment: Also , what do we do if Explorer wont quit by clicking X in the corner while holding CTRL? Mine doesn't want to close that way.

Answer (score 2):

This will sort all folders and files in same Order.

1. Go to File Explorer (any drive)
2. Right-Click and sort by (to any option you need)
3. View pane > Options > Folder Options

   1. View > Apply to Folders > Ok
4. Right-Click on the same directory > Properties

   1. Customize this Folder (Dialogue Box Opens)
   2. Optimize this Folder for General Items
   3. Tick *Also apply this template to all subfolders*
   4. Apply > Ok.

Now all of the files and folders are sorted in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me alone. I also had to change my folder type to "General Items".

1. Right-click the folder and click **Properties**.
2. Click the **Customize** tab.
3. Under the first menu, *Optimize this folder for*, select **General Items**.

After this extra step, Windows Explorer always picked the sort order I'd set using the other solutions for this specific folder. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

This works in Windows 10:

1. Go to your top-level directory in Explorer
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> to open Folder Options
3. View tab > Apply to Folders

It should set the same view options you have in your top-level directory for the rest of the filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

It's simple,

1. open any folder, for example, **Download**, documents, etc.
2. Apply your desired sorting to that folder.
3. Once you are ready with your sort, click on **3 dots**, aside view in the top menu bar, and choose **option** menu below.
4. Inside the **option** menu, go to the **view** tab and click on **Apply to Folders**.
5. You are good to go. Your sorting will be applied to all folders.

Comment: We really want answers to be unique.  I am struggling to see how this adds any more information than a previous answer.