# Windows 7 or 10: How can I force every Explorer view to be in "Details" view always (including "Open" and "Save as" dialogs)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, save-as

I would like every instance of Explorer to always open in "Details" view, regardless of the folder I'm viewing.  I like this default to never, ever change; I can select different views if I want them.  I would like this for File Explorer and all "Save as" and "Open" dialogs.

Windows 10, but I'd even switch back to Windows 7 if this is possible.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no way to make the change to details permanent and "never, ever change".  I have been using xPlorer2 (zabkat) since XP because xPlorer2 keeps its basic settings in a file (and registry) and it does not ever change.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1565096/how-to-force-custom-default-sort-by-options-for-all-folder-types-in-windows-expl/1565131#1565131. YOU HAVE TO DO THEM IN THE RIGHT ORDER.

Comment: Also Libraries are treated as search results so settings aren't saved. Don't use libraries.

Comment: Libraries & Search results do save views, and their default icon mode can be modified as well.

Answer (score 0):

This **PowerShell** will create custom view templates for the logged in user with the icon mode set to **Details** for all ***FolderTypes***, including Libraries, and Search Results. Just copy & paste the code into a **PowerShell** window. Press <**Enter**> to execute.

```
$FolderTypes = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'

cd 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer'

$CopySplat = @{
   Destination = { $RelPath = ($_.PSParentPath -split 'Explorer\\')[-1]
                   If ( -not ( Test-Path $RelPath )) { md $RelPath -force | out-null }
                   $RelPath }
   PassThru    = $True
}
$spSplat = @{
   Name        = 'LogicalViewMode'
   Value       = 1
   PassThru    = $True
}

gci $FolderTypes -recurse | ? Property -contains 'LogicalViewMode' |
     Copy-Item  @CopySplat | Set-ItemProperty @spSplat | Remove-ItemProperty -Name IconSize -ea Silent
```

This doesn't override saved views or custom templates created by **Apply to Folders**. To delete saved views:

```
$BagMRU = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU'
$Bags   = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
$BagMRU, $Bags | Remove-Item -recurse
gps explorer | spps
```

And to remove **Apply to Folders** templates:

```
$Defaults = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults'
Remove-ItemProperty $Defaults * -ea silent
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [WinSetView](https://lesferch.github.io/WinSetView/).

See the documentation for details.