# Changing to List View in File Explorer - Everywhere

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-11

My question is identical to [this Microsoft post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/changing-to-list-view-in-file-explorer-everywhere/4e190712-d726-499d-bfed-f26ee77abe06), which didn't receive any viable answers. I'm running `Windows 10` (version doesn't matter, same behavior in all versions) and I simply want all my folders in all my drives to display in `List View` rather than `Details View` or otherwise.

For any given folder, this can be done by going to `Windows Explorer -> View -> List`, one by one.

Many people mistakenly believe that what I'm asking for can then be accomplished by going to `Windows Explorer -> Options -> Change folder and search options -> View -> Apply to Folders`. That simply doesn't work. In fact I don't know what it even does. After doing that I can find folders all over my system that continue to open in `Details View` by default.

Important: In some cases I do want to be able to change a folder to `Details View` or etc, but 95% of the time (and by default), I just want the compact `List View` for all folders.

Is there a registry hack or something? How can this be done?

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1565096/how-to-force-custom-default-sort-by-options-for-all-folder-types-in-windows-expl/1565131#1565131. So you don't need to do anything.

Comment: My folders work correctly. I don't do anything special but know the rules. I don't set defaults. Settings inherit if none are saved. Saved settings are saved by the path you het there. `This PC\C:\Windows` is completely different to `C:\Windows`. It has 25 years of development work and user testing behind it. If you don't think about it it works.

Comment: I guess you don't need to think about it if you like their defaults, which I don't.

Comment: There is no issue with folders and their overall operation.  But the various views do not keep the same over time.

Comment: It learns your stuff.

Comment: Your procedure is wrong to it say apply to _folders of this type_.  To list the types of folders type `(@For /f "tokens=* delims=" %A in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes /f "CanonicalName" /v "CanonicalName" /s ^| findstr /c:"Name" ^| Sort') Do @Echo %A)`

Comment: Why was the answer that says there is no answer marked as "Answer" and my answer, one of several ways to set a global icon mode, was ignored?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy & paste the following code into an ***Admin* PowerShell** window. This will set list as the default mode for all *FolderTypes*.

```
$FT = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
gci $FT -Recurse | ? Property -Contains 'LogicalVIewMode' | %{
$_.Name -match 'FolderTypes\\(.+)\\TopViews' | out-null
$matches[1]
} | select -unique | %{
    New-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\$_" -force |
    Set-ItemProperty -Name 'Mode' -Value 3 -PassThru |
    Set-ItemProperty -Name 'LogicalViewMode' -Value 4
}
```

To delete any saved views so your new defaults appear consistently, delete the `BagMRU` and `Bags` registry keys:

```
ri 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU' -Recurse
ri 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' -Recurse
```

Comment: Keith, this is incredible. It really does work. THANK YOU!!

Comment: This would be a little more useful/compact if in a powershell file that could be executed as such. Would I just paste all lines above into a .ps file and run it from powershell?

Comment: Sure. As long as you're aware the safeguards PowerShell has in place regarding ExecutionPolicy & invoking script files via path rather than name. I don't feel like explaining that every time I offer a code snippet, especially for things like this which tend to be one-off tasks.

Comment: This seems to work well in Win11 also - just did it!

Answer (score 1):

Following Keith's answer, to use different type of views, you have to change the value of the `LogicalViewMode` property.

- `0`: Medium-sized icons View
- `1`: Details View
- `2`: Tiles View
- `4`: List View
- `5`: Content View

So, if you want to use the details view everywhere, the script becomes:

```
$FT = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
gci $FT -Recurse | ? Property -Contains 'LogicalVIewMode' | %{
$_.Name -match 'FolderTypes\\(.+)\\TopViews' | out-null
$matches[1]
} | select -unique | %{
    New-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\$_" -force |
    Set-ItemProperty -Name 'Mode' -Value 3 -PassThru |
    Set-ItemProperty -Name 'LogicalViewMode' -Value 1
}
```

You can just throw it in an admin powershell window.

And to revert the changes:

```
ri 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU' -Recurse
ri 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' -Recurse
```

Comment: Thanks Dat...helpful.